# efficient way to calculate the empirical probabilities of actions for a given state in R

Tags: r

I would like to calculate the probabilities of an action being taken given the set of states s1,s2,...,s6. However, I'd like to append this probability as another column in my dataframe. I know how to calculate these probabilities by just looping through each row in the table and then doing lookups, but I think it'd help to have a vectorized solution.

I know the empirical probability is `length(df[(s1==x1 & s2==x2 & ... & s6==x6 & action==a),])/length(df[(s1==x1 & s2==x2 & ... & s6==x6),])` but I need help calculating this for each row and creating a new column `df$b` for my dataframe.

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: It’s best to avoid using images of code/data and [here’s why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Note that you can quickly get your data out of your R session and onto SO by calling `dput(my_df)` and copy/pasting the result.  If your data are large, do `dput(head(my_df))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[ , numer := .N, by=.(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, action)]
df[ , denom := .N, by=.(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6)]

df[ , b:= numer/denom]
```

Comment: Ah but I want to find the proportion of rows with s1,...,s6 AND the specified action out of the number of rows with the matching s1,...,s6.

Comment: That will still be over the total number of rows. I want the denominator to be the total number of rows matching s1--s6 and the numerator to be the number of rows matching s1---s6 AND the action.